# Makefile: fatal error: No such file or directory

Tags: c, makefile

There's tons of questions regarding this issue but none have helped... I've tried it all.

I have a

- `proj.c` file I want to compile and it depends on `Client_linked_list.h` and `POOL_check_linked_list.h`.
- `Client_linked_list` that depends on nothing but itself
- `POOL_check_linked_lis`t that depends on `Client_linked_list.h`

This is my makefile code

```
CFLAGS =-ansi -Wall -pedantic
CC = gcc
LDFLAGS=-lm

.PHONY: all clean run

all: proj

proj: Client_linked_list.o POOL_check_linked_list.o proj.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o proj proj.o Client_linked_list.o POOL_check_linked_list.o 

Client_linked_list.o: Client_linked_list.c Client_linked_list.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c Client_linked_list.c

POOL_check_linked_list.o: POOL_check_linked_list.c POOL_check_linked_list.h Client_linked_list.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c POOL_check_linked_list.c

proj.o: proj.c Client_linked_list.h POOL_check_linked_list.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o proj.o -c proj.c

clean:
    @echo Cleaning...
    rm -f proj Client_linked_list POOL_check_linked_list
```

This is the error message I'm getting:

```
gcc -ansi -Wall -pedantic -c Client_linked_list.c
Client_linked_list.c:10:32: fatal error: Client_linked_list.h: No such file or directory 
compilation terminated. make: *** [makefile:20:Client_linked_list.o] Error 1
```

The files are all in the same directory!

Comment: it's definitely Client_linked_list.h with a capital C?

Comment: Could you please copy and paste the `#include` line that tries to read `Client_linked_list.h` into the question?  Also, the **complete and unedited** output of `ls -l` in the directory containing all the files.

Comment: (Did you know you can edit your question? The tiny gray word "edit" under the tags is a button.  Yes, it's bad UI design.  Sorry. Stack Exchange refuses to fix this.)

Comment: (Incidentally, you probably should be using `-std=gnu11` instead of `-ansi`.  `-ansi` is equivalent to `-std=c89`, which selects the old 1989 C standard that you probably don't want, and all of the hyperconformant `-std=cXX` modes can potentially expose bugs in the system headers.)

Comment: How do you `#include` the file?  Try `#include "Client_linked_list.h"` rather than `#include <Client_linked_list.h>` or add `-I./` to your compile command.

Comment: @user253751 definitely.´

Comment: "How do you #include the file? Try #include "Client_linked_list.h" rather than #include <Client_linked_list.h> or add -I./ to your compile command." This was it! I feel stupid :'( thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `-I` option in your CFLAGS, pointing towards your include folder.

The error seems to come from your compiler which doesn't know where your header file is.

Comment: If all the files are in the same directory as OP says, then this should not be necessary.

Comment: It really looks like it, until OP¨posts the output of his working directory it's gonna be hard working on this.

Comment: I also can't comment on his post because of my reputation so I'm trying to help like that, if it is not what is searched after I'll remove the answer

Comment: I had tried that. 

"How do you #include the file? Try #include "Client_linked_list.h" rather than #include <Client_linked_list.h> or add -I./ to your compile command." ( pointed out by @G.M. ) this was it...